# Out of memory on X-byte allocation

Tags: android

I suspect I'm facing a memory management issue which is an Out of memory on a X-byte alocation causing my app to crash (specifically on the Samsung S3) after the calling of several activities.

So just explain my screen flow:

splash screen -> log in screen -> menu screen (from menu screen user can call three different activities) -> user calls activity 1 and the app crashes here OR works -> user calls activity 2 and app definitely crashes.

All the above activities have very low sized images (~44kb) as backgrounds (this is a specification/requirement of the app)

Below is how I've essentially created each progrmatically activity and set the backgrounds (the image R.drawable.bgnd is of size 44kb and so are the other images):

```
    public class FincCalcScreenNormal  extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Main RL params
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rllayoutParams 
                = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        // Create main relative layout
        RelativeLayout rlMain = new RelativeLayout(this);
        rlMain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd);
        rlMain.setLayoutParams(rllayoutParams);

    // Set the activity content to an explicit view. 
    setContentView(rlMain);

       }
}
```

The image below shows the stacktrace of the app on the S3 when it crashes. From the stacktrace at the bottom of the image you will notice the area I've circled in red. This is the line in code where by the crashes.

[image]

I've read through the android documentation specifically this http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#ReleaseMemoryAsUiGone and attempted to use the onTrimMemory() method to release memory when the UI becomes hidden but it didnt make a difference.

Below is a list of all the images i utilise in the app with regards to file size:

A JPEG backgroundimage for activity -> 110kb

A JPEG backgroundimage for activity -> 80kb

A JPEG backgroundimage for activity -> 76kb

A JPEG backgroundimage for activity -> 68kb

A JPEG backgroundimage for activity -> 59kb

A JPEG backgroundimage for activity -> 51kb

A JPEG backgroundimage for activity -> 44kb

A JPEG backgroundimage for activity -> 42kb

A png image for a button background -> 38kb

A png image for a button background -> 35kb

A png image for a button background -> 31kb

A JPEG backgroundimage for activity -> 31kb

A JPEG backgroundimage for activity -> 30kb

A JPEG backgroundimage for activity -> 29kb

A png image for a button background -> 28kb

A png image for a button background -> 27kb

A png image for a button background -> 18kb

A png image for a button background -> 16kb

A png image for a button background -> 16kb

A png image for a button background -> 13kb

A png image for a button background -> 6kb

A png image for a button background -> 6kb

A png image for a button background -> 5kb

A png image for a button background -> 4kb

A png image for a button background -> 3kb

A png image for a button background -> 2kb

A png image for a button background -> 2kb

A png image for a button background -> 2kb

A png image for a button background -> 2kb

A png image for a button background -> 2kb

A png image for a button background -> 1kb

The above amounts to a total of 880K and compared to the allocated memory of the app based on the stacktrace I posted which is ~14mb then I don't get why I'm having this problem.

Any ideas are appreciated as I've been stuck on the issue for several days.

Comment: what resource is `R.drawable.bgnd`? Is it a large image?

Comment: Does the problem disappear if you specify some background color instead?

Comment: @18446744073709551615: Yeah the problem disappears when i use some background color.

Comment: @18446744073709551615: Yeah the problem disappears when i use some background color. I get why as setting a background color consumes less memory but I was wondering how can i "help" the garbage collector with regards to freeing up the memory that the previous activities have consumed with regards to the images in those previous activities? As I mentioned i read the android documentation link in my post above but cant seem to grasp how to free memory consumed in a previous activity once a new activity is called.

Comment: Do you really need a large image for the background? Android can scale it for you; in addition, there is an option of using 9-patch png. If you need a gradient, you can define a _shape_ with a _gradient_ inside via xml as a _drawable/_.

Comment: @18446744073709551615: so this means if i were to reduce all my images to be in and around 30kb then it might solve the problem? in addition i've gone thru my images and listed them above in size which in total is 880kb. i wonder why this would cause an issue with regards to the 14mb byte allocation as indicated in the stacktrace.

Comment: Some image formats are packed. What is X*Y resolution of your image? Probably it becomes large after unpacking.

Comment: the resolutions range from 1280x800 to 800x480.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that `R.drawable.bgnd` is ~44kb, but from the log message it seems like your app is trying to allocate a much larger space. Your application may have multiple drawable folders with different qualifiers (e.g., drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi). Could you double check each of the drawable folders and verify that the `bgnd` files are definitely ~44kb?

Comment: i've cross checked my background images and they are around 44kb. I was wondering how can i "help" the garbage collector with regards to freeing up the memory that the previous activities have consumed with regards to the images in those previous activities? As I mentioned i read the android documentation link in my post above but cant seem to grasp how to free memory consumed in a previous activity once a new activity is called.

Comment: 44KB would hardly give you a 14_745_616 byte allocation, it is 14M! What image format do you use? You may try to use a small png and see if it gets better.

Comment: @18446744073709551615: so this means if i were to reduce all my images to be in and around 30kb then it might solve the problem? in addition i've gone thru my images and listed them above in size which in total is 880kb. i wonder why this would cause an issue with regards to the 14mb byte allocation as indicated in the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

*JPEG typically achieves 10:1 compression with little perceptible loss in image quality. [[link]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)*

I suspect your JPEG images become very large when uncompressed, and Android does need to uncompress them to display them. Try to replace them with small PNGs. (Or, more precisely, with images of smaller X*Y size.)

Comment: so say the images are all changed to pngs of 30kb or so ... would this help?

Comment: I think what would help is a smaller number of pixels. I expect png not to use such compression, not to hide large uncompressed size behind a small file, and make you reduce the number of pixels in the course of trying to reduce the png size. What is the _pixel resolution_ of your images?

Comment: the resolutions of the background images are 1280x800, 1280x720, 1024x600, 800x480